# Trying to solve symmetric difference using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, symmetric-difference

I am trying to figure out a solution for symmetric 
difference using javascript that accomplishes the following
objectives:

- accepts an unspecified number of arrays as arguments
- preserves the original order of the numbers in the arrays
- does not remove duplicates of numbers in single arrays
- removes duplicates occurring across arrays

Thus, for example,
if the input is ([1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4]),
the solution would be, [1, 1, 6, 5, 4].

I am trying to solve this as challenge given by an online
coding community. The exact instructions of the challenge
state,

> Create a function that takes two or more arrays and returns an array
>   of the symmetric difference of the provided arrays.
>
> The mathematical term symmetric difference refers to the elements in
>   two sets that are in either the first or second set, but not in both.

Although my solution below finds the numbers that are
unique to each array, it eliminates all numbers occuring
more than once and does not keep the order of the numbers.

My question is very close to the one asked at [finding symmetric difference/unique elements in multiple arrays in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468692/finding-symmetric-difference-unique-elements-in-multiple-arrays-in-javascript).   However, the solution
does not preserve the original order of the numbers and does not preserve duplicates of unique numbers occurring in single arrays.

```
function sym(args){
    var arr = [];
    var result = [];
    var units;
    var index = {};
    for(var i in arguments){
        units = arguments[i];

    for(var j = 0; j < units.length; j++){
         arr.push(units[j]);
        }
    }

    arr.forEach(function(a){
        if(!index[a]){
            index[a] = 0;
        }
            index[a]++;

    });

       for(var l in index){
           if(index[l] === 1){
               result.push(+l);
           }
       }

    return result;
}
symsym([1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4]); // => Desired answer: [1, 1, 6. 5. 4]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a version that uses the `Set` object to make for faster lookup.  Here's the basic logic:

1. It puts each array passed as an argument into a separate Set object (to faciliate fast lookup).
2. Then, it iterates each passed in array and compares it to the other Set objects (the ones not made from the array being iterated).
3. If the item is not found in any of the other Sets, then it is added to the result.

So, it starts with the first array `[1, 1, 2, 6]`.  Since `1` is not found in either of the other arrays, each of the first two `1` values are added to the result.  Then `2` is found in the second set so it is not added to the result.  Then `6` is not found in either of the other two sets so it is added to the result.  The same process repeats for the second array `[2, 3, 5]` where `2` and `3` are found in other Sets, but `5` is not so `5` is added to the result.  And, for the last array, only `4` is not found in the other Sets.  So, the final result is `[1,1,6,5,4]`.

The `Set` objects are used for convenience and performance.  One could use `.indexOf()` to look them up in each array or one could make your own Set-like lookup with a plain object if you didn't want to rely on the Set object.  There's also a partial polyfill for the Set object that would work here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422).

```js
function symDiff() {
    var sets = [], result = [];
    // make copy of arguments into an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    // put each array into a set for easy lookup
    args.forEach(function(arr) {
        sets.push(new Set(arr));
    });
    // now see which elements in each array are unique 
    // e.g. not contained in the other sets
    args.forEach(function(array, arrayIndex) {
        // iterate each item in the array
        array.forEach(function(item) {
            var found = false;
            // iterate each set (use a plain for loop so it's easier to break)
            for (var setIndex = 0; setIndex < sets.length; setIndex++) {
                // skip the set from our own array
                if (setIndex !== arrayIndex) {
                    if (sets[setIndex].has(item)) {
                        // if the set has this item
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
}

var r = symDiff([1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4]);
log(r);

function log(x) {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.textContent = JSON.stringify(x);
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

One key part of this code is how it compares a given item to the Sets from the other arrays.  It just iterates through the list of Set objects, but it skips the Set object that has the same index in the array as the array being iterated.  That skips the Set made from this array so it's only looking for items that exist in other arrays.  That allows it to retain duplicates that occur in only one array.

---

Here's a version that uses the `Set` object if it's present, but inserts a teeny replacement if not (so this will work in more older browsers):

```js
function symDiff() {
    var sets = [], result = [], LocalSet;
    if (typeof Set === "function") {
        try {
            // test to see if constructor supports iterable arg
            var temp = new Set([1,2,3]);
            if (temp.size === 3) {
                LocalSet = Set;
            }
        } catch(e) {}
    }
    if (!LocalSet) {
        // use teeny polyfill for Set
        LocalSet = function(arr) {
            this.has = function(item) {
                return arr.indexOf(item) !== -1;
            }
        }
    }
    // make copy of arguments into an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    // put each array into a set for easy lookup
    args.forEach(function(arr) {
        sets.push(new LocalSet(arr));
    });
    // now see which elements in each array are unique 
    // e.g. not contained in the other sets
    args.forEach(function(array, arrayIndex) {
        // iterate each item in the array
        array.forEach(function(item) {
            var found = false;
            // iterate each set (use a plain for loop so it's easier to break)
            for (var setIndex = 0; setIndex < sets.length; setIndex++) {
                // skip the set from our own array
                if (setIndex !== arrayIndex) {
                    if (sets[setIndex].has(item)) {
                        // if the set has this item
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
}


var r = symDiff([1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4]);
log(r);

function log(x) {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.textContent = JSON.stringify(x);
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This had me stumped. I could not, for the life of me, figure out how to do the iteration and comparison of elements that your solution so clearly displays. Many thanks!

Comment: @davisec52 - I just noticed that the other solution you linked to in your question was also mine.  I guess I just like these kinds of problems.

Comment: I added a version of the code that works in IE (back to IE9).  In IE's infinite wisdom (even IE11), even though it supports the `Set` object, it does not support passing an array to the constructor.  So, the second version of the code above tests for either the lack of the `Set` object or the IE poorly functioning one and uses a teeny polyfill replacement that does just what this function needs.

Comment: Your answers have been very instructive. It has also been instructive comparing these answers to the answer you gave at the link provided in the question up top. I am still very much a novice, and I did not know about the Set object nor the use of has (as in sets[setsIndex].has[item]).

Comment: @davisec52 - The `Set` object is a new feature that is supported in newer browsers.  It is part of the ES6 Javascript specification.  That's why I provided the second code example that works in browsers that don't support the `Set` object.

Answer (score 27):

As with all problems, it's best to start off writing an algorithm:

> Concatenate versions of the arrays, where each array is filtered to contain those elements which no array other than the current one contains

Then just write that down in JS:

```
function sym() {
  var arrays = [].slice.apply(arguments);

  return [].concat.apply([],               // concatenate
    arrays.map(                            // versions of the arrays
      function(array, i) {                 // where each array
        return array.filter(               // is filtered to contain
          function(elt) {                  // those elements which
            return !arrays.some(           // no array
              function(a, j) {             // 
                return i !== j             // other than the current one
                  && a.indexOf(elt) >= 0   // contains
                ;
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }
    )
  );
}
```

Non-commented version, written more succinctly using ES6:

```
function sym(...arrays) {
  return [].concat(arrays . 
    map((array, i) => array . 
      filter(elt => !arrays . 
        some((a, j) => i !== j && a.indexOf(elt) >= 0))));
}
```

Comment: sym([3, 3, 3, 2, 5], [2, 1, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 9, 8], [1]) should return [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], but the above two solutions don't.

Answer (score 9):

I came across this question in my research of the same coding challenge on FCC.  I was able to solve it using `for` and `while` loops, but had some trouble solving using the recommended `Array.reduce()`.  After learning a ton about `.reduce` and other array methods, I thought I'd share my solutions as well.

This is the first way I solved it, without using `.reduce`.

```
function sym() {
  var arrays = [].slice.call(arguments);

  function diff(arr1, arr2) {
    var arr = [];

    arr1.forEach(function(v) {
      if ( !~arr2.indexOf(v) && !~arr.indexOf(v) ) {
        arr.push( v );
      }
    });

    arr2.forEach(function(v) {
      if ( !~arr1.indexOf(v) && !~arr.indexOf(v) ) {
        arr.push( v );
      }
    });
    return arr;
  }

  var result = diff(arrays.shift(), arrays.shift());

  while (arrays.length > 0) {
    result = diff(result, arrays.shift());
  }

  return result;
}
```

After learning and trying various method combinations, I came up with this that I think is pretty succinct and readable.

```
function sym() {
  var arrays = [].slice.call(arguments);

  function diff(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(function (v) {
      return !~arr2.indexOf(v);
    });
  }

  return arrays.reduce(function (accArr, curArr) { 
    return [].concat( diff(accArr, curArr), diff(curArr, accArr) )
    .filter(function (v, i, self) { return self.indexOf(v) === i; });
  });

}
```

That last `.filter` line I thought was pretty cool to dedup an array.  I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array), but modified it to use the 3rd callback parameter instead of the named array due to the method chaining.

This challenge was a lot of fun!

Answer (score 6):

```js
// Set difference, a.k.a. relative compliment
const diff = (a, b) => a.filter(v => !b.includes(v))

const symDiff = (first, ...rest) => 
  rest.reduce(
    (acc, x) => [
      ...diff(acc, x), 
      ...diff(x, acc),
    ], 
    first,
  )    

/* - - - */
console.log(symDiff([1, 3], ['Saluton', 3]))    // [1, 'Saluton']
console.log(symDiff([1, 3], [2, 3], [2, 8, 5])) // [1, 8, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [_.xor](https://lodash.com/docs#xor) or copy lodash code.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple, yet readable solution:

```js
 
/*
This filters arr1 and arr2 from elements which are in both arrays
and returns concatenated results from filtering.
*/
function symDiffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(elem => !arr2.includes(elem))
             .concat(arr2.filter(elem => !arr1.includes(elem)));
}

/*
Add and use this if you want to filter more than two arrays at a time.
*/
function symDiffArrays(...arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce(symDiffArray, []);
}

console.log(symDiffArray([1, 3], ['Saluton', 3])); // [1, 'Saluton']
console.log(symDiffArrays([1, 3], [2, 3], [2, 8, 5])); // [1, 8, 5]
```

Used functions:  [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) | [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) | [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 4):

```
function sym(arr1, arr2, ...rest) {

  //creating a array which has unique numbers from both the arrays
  const union = [...new Set([...arr1,...arr2])];

  // finding the Symmetric Difference between those two arrays
  const diff = union.filter((num)=> !(arr1.includes(num) && arr2.includes(num)))

  //if there are more than 2 arrays
  if(rest.length){
    // recurrsively call till rest become 0 
    // i.e.  diff of 1,2 will be the first parameter so every recurrsive call will reduce     //  the arrays till diff between all of them are calculated.

    return sym(diff, rest[0], ...rest.slice(1))
  }
  return diff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a Map with a count of all unique values (across arrays). Then concat all arrays, and filter non unique values using the Map.

```js
const symsym = (...args) => {
  // create a Map from the unique value of each array
  const m = args.reduce((r, a) => {
    // get unique values of array, and add to Map
    new Set(a).forEach((n) => r.set(n, (r.get(n) || 0) + 1));
    
    return r;
  }, new Map());
  
  // combine all arrays
  return [].concat(...args)
    // remove all items that appear more than once in the map
    .filter((n) => m.get(n) === 1); 
};

console.log(symsym([1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4])); // => Desired answer: [1, 1, 6, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

> This is the JS code using higher order functions

```js
    function sym(args) {
      var output;
      output = [].slice.apply(arguments).reduce(function(previous, current) {
        current.filter(function(value, index, self) { //for unique
          return self.indexOf(value) === index;
        }).map(function(element) { //pushing array
          var loc = previous.indexOf(element);
          a = [loc !== -1 ? previous.splice(loc, 1) : previous.push(element)];
        });
        return previous;
      }, []);
      document.write(output);
      return output;
    }

    sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

And it would return the output as: [3,5,4]

Comment: Could you please print the result when running your code snippet please ?

Answer (score 2):

Pure javascript solution.

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
var arr3= [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++ ){
    var unique = true;
     for(var j=0; j < arr2.length; j++){
          if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
               unique = false;
               break;
          }
     }
  if(unique){
    arr3.push(arr1[i]);}
  }
 return arr3;
}

function symDiff(arr1, arr2){
  return diff(arr1,arr2).concat(diff(arr2,arr1));
}

symDiff([1, "calf", 3, "piglet"], [7, "filly"])
//[1, "calf", 3, "piglet", 7, "filly"]
```

Answer (score 2):

My short solution. At the end, I removed duplicates by filter().

```
function sym() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var almost = args.reduce(function(a,b){
    return b.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;})
    .concat(a.filter(function(i){return b.indexOf(i)<0;}));
  });
  return almost.filter(function(el, pos){return almost.indexOf(el) == pos;});
}

sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]);

//Result: [4,5,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sym(args) {
  var initialArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var combinedTotalArray = initialArray.reduce(symDiff);

  
  // Iterate each element in array,  find values not present in other array and push values in combinedDualArray if value is not there already
  // Repeat for the other array (change roles)
  function symDiff(arrayOne, arrayTwo){
    var combinedDualArray = [];
    arrayOne.forEach(function(el, i){
      if(!arrayTwo.includes(el) && !combinedDualArray.includes(el)){
        combinedDualArray.push(el);
      }
    });
      
    arrayTwo.forEach(function(el, i){
      if(!arrayOne.includes(el) && !combinedDualArray.includes(el)){
        combinedDualArray.push(el);
      }
    });
    combinedDualArray.sort();
    return combinedDualArray;
  }
  
  return combinedTotalArray;
}

console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]));
```

Answer (score 2):

This function removes duplicates because the original concept of symmetric difference operates over sets. In this example, the function operates on the sets this way: ((A △ B) △ C) △ D ...

```js
function sym(...args) {
    return args.reduce((old, cur) => {
        let oldSet = [...new Set(old)]
        let curSet = [...new Set(cur)]
        return [
            ...oldSet.filter(i => !curSet.includes(i)),
            ...curSet.filter(i => !oldSet.includes(i))
        ]
    })
}

// Running> sym([1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4])
console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4]))
// Return>  [1, 6, 5, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation too for your answer, so that any future audience gets to know that approach for solving such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```js
function sym() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  
  var getSym = function(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(function(each, idx) {
      return arr2.indexOf(each) === -1 && arr1.indexOf(each, idx + 1) === -1;
    }).concat(arr2.filter(function(each, idx) {
      return arr1.indexOf(each) === -1 && arr2.indexOf(each, idx + 1) === -1;
    }));
  };
  
  var result = getSym(args[0], args[1]);
  var len = args.length - 1, i = 2;
  while (--len) {
    result = [].concat(getSym(result, args[i]));
    i++;
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.info(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [6, 8], [7, 8], [9]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: Use the lookup inside a map instead of an array

```
function sym(...vs){
    var has = {};
    //flatten values
    vs.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b)).
        //if element does not exist add it (value==1)
        //or mark it as multiply found value > 1
        forEach(value=>{has[value] = (has[value]||0)+1});
    return Object.keys(has).filter(x=>has[x]==1).map(x=>parseInt(x,10));
}
console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4],[5,7], [5]));//[3,4,7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey if anyone is interested this is my solution:

```js
function sym (...args) {
  let fileteredArgs = [];
  let symDiff = [];
  args.map(arrayEl =>
    fileteredArgs.push(arrayEl.filter((el, key) =>
      arrayEl.indexOf(el) === key
      )
    )
  );

  fileteredArgs.map(elArr => {
    elArr.map(el => {
      let index = symDiff.indexOf(el);
      if (index === -1) {
        symDiff.push(el);
      } else {
        symDiff.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  });

  return (symDiff);
}

console.log(sym([1, 2, 3, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
let a=[1, 1, 2, 6]
let b=[2, 3, 5];
let c= [2, 3, 4]

let result=[...a,...b].filter(item=>!(a.includes(item) && b.includes(item) ))
result=[...result,...c].filter(item=>!(b.includes(item) && c.includes(item) ))

console.log(result)  //[1, 1, 6, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise solution using

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Implicit return](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/17665/implicit-return)

```js
const symPair = (a, b) => 
  [...a.filter(item => !b.includes(item)),
  ...b.filter(item => !a.includes(item))]

const sym = (...args) => [...new Set(args.reduce(symPair))]
```

The function `symPair` works for two input arrays, and the function `sym` works for two or more arrays, using `symPair` as a reducer.

```js
const symPair = (a, b) => 
  [...a.filter(item => !b.includes(item)),
  ...b.filter(item => !a.includes(item))]

const sym = (...args) => [...new Set(args.reduce(symPair))]

console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const removeDuplicates = (data) => Array.from(new Set(data));
const getSymmetric = (data) => (val) => data.indexOf(val) === data.lastIndexOf(val)

function sym(...args) {
  let joined = [];
  args.forEach((arr) => {
    joined = joined.concat(removeDuplicates(arr));
    joined = joined.filter(getSymmetric(joined))
  });
 return joined;
}


console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked fine all the scenarios. Try the below code

```
function sym() {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      var setA = arguments[i].filter((val) => !arguments[i + 1].includes(val));
      var setB = arguments[i + 1].filter((val) => !arguments[i].includes(val));
      result = [...setA, ...setB];
      i = i + 1;
    } else {
      var setA = arguments[i].filter((val) => !result.includes(val));
      var setB = result.filter((val) => !arguments[i].includes(val));
      result = [...setA, ...setB];
    }
  }
  return result.filter((c, index) => {
    return result.indexOf(c) === index;
  }).sort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code passed all test cases for the similar question on [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/coding-interview-prep/algorithms/find-the-symmetric-difference). Below is code for the same.

```
function sym(...args) {
  const result = args.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
    if (curr.length > acc.length) {
      const arr = curr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
        if(a.includes(c)){
        }
        if (!acc.includes(c) && !a.includes(c)) {
          a.push(c);
        }
        if (!curr.includes(acc[i]) && i < acc.length) {
          a.push(acc[i])
        }
        return a;
      }, []);
      return [...arr];
    } else {
      const arr = acc.reduce((a, c, i) => {
        if(a.includes(c)){
        }
        if (!curr.includes(c) && !a.includes(c)) {
          a.push(c);
        }
        if (!acc.includes(curr[i]) && i < curr.length) {
          a.push(curr[i])
        }
        return a;
      }, []);
      return [...arr]
    }
  });
  let ans = new Set([...result])
  return [...ans]
}

sym([1,2,3,3],[5, 2, 1, 4,5]);
```