# Comparing 2 arrays for differences (find symmetric difference)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, symmetric-difference

This should be a simple algorithm but I can't wrap my head around the logic. I need to take 2 arrays and keep only the values that are found in one array or the other and not both.

For example if I have

```
arr1 [1,2,3,6]

arr2 [2,3,4,5,7]
```

I want to have 2 arrays again being

```
arr1 [1,6]
arr2 [4,5,7]
```

EDIT:

I removed my old code and put in some other working code. Still not very pretty but at least working. All I would need to do is store arr3 into arr1 and arr4 into arr2.

```
    var arr3 = [];
    var arr4 = [];

    var foundMatch = false;

    //find all arr1 elements that don't match arr2 elements
    //store into arr4
    for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
    {
        foundMatch = false;
        for(var j=0; j<arr2.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])
            {
                console.log("match found for [%s] [%s]", i, j);
                foundMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!foundMatch)
        {
            arr4.push(arr1[i]);
        }
    }

    //find all arr2 elements not in arr1
    //store in arr3
    for(var i=0; i<arr2.length; i++)
    {
        foundMatch = false;
        for(var j=0; j<arr1.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr2[i] == arr1[j])
            {
                console.log("match found for [%s] [%s]", i, j);
                foundMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!foundMatch)
        {
            arr3.push(arr2[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: http://ramdajs.com/docs/#difference

Comment: Also note that its much, much easier to push the non-dupe values into a new array than to splice the existing ones....

Comment: Here is an [existing Stack Overflow question that solves finding the _symmetric difference_ of many arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834946/trying-to-solve-symmetric-difference-using-javascript).

Comment: I don't exactly want the symmetric difference into a single array. I want each array to keep their non matching values.

Comment: @JaredSmith I appreciate the link to ramdajs.

Comment: @Crash667 its one of my favorites: its popular enough, well-designed enough, etc. The author is also very active on SO meaning ramda questions tend to get reasonably fast canonical answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest solution in terms of time complexity is to create a [`Set`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) or a `hash` from one array -> `O(N)`, then iterate through the other to compare if an element is not the set -> `O(M)` -> and then add it to the diffs array.
The main benefit here is that Set lookup time is constant.
This solution also has space complexity of `O(N)` for building the set.

You can repeat this for the other array as well, giving you total of `O(N) + O(M) + O(N) + O(M)` which, when constant factors are removed, is just `O(N+M)` time complexity.

Building the set for the second array gives total space complexity as `O(N+M)`.

```js
// Total complexity
// Time:  O(N+M)
// Space: O(N+M)

// time complexities for each step shown bellow

let N = [1,2,3,6]
let M = [2,3,4,5,7]

const setForN = new Set(N); // O(N)
const setForM = new Set(M); // O(M)

// O(N + M) at this point

const answerN = N.filter(n => !setForM.has(n)) // O(N)
const answerM = M.filter(m => !setForN.has(m)) // O(M)

// O(N + M) + O(N + M) at this point, which is just O(N + M)

console.log(answerN, answerM);
```

ES5 solution:

```js
var N = [1,2,3,6]
var M = [2,3,4,5,7]

var setOfNumbers = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(set, item) {
    return Object.defineProperty(set, item, { value: item });
  }, Object.create(null));
}
var setForN = setOfNumbers(N);
var setForM = setOfNumbers(M);

var answerN = N.filter(function(n) { return typeof setForM[n] !== 'number' });
var answerM = M.filter(function(m) { return typeof setForN[m] !== 'number' });

console.log(answerN, answerM);
```

---

Another way is to do what other answers suggest which is to, for each element in `N` -> `O(N)`, check if it exists in `M` -> `O(M)`, and add it to the diffs array. Repeat for the other array.

This has better, constant, space complexity `O(1)` but slower quadratic `O(N*M)` time.

```js
// Total Complexity:
// Time:  O(N*M)
// Space: O(1)

let N = [1,2,3,6]
let M = [2,3,4,5,7]

// For every element in N -> O(N)
// Iterate through M and check if it's there -> O(M)
// Total: O(N*M)
const answerN = N.filter(n => !M.includes(n));

// For every element in M -> O(M)
// Iterate through N and check if it's there -> O(N)
// Total: O(M*N)
const answerM = M.filter(m => !N.includes(m));

// O(N*M) + O(M*N) at this point, which is just O(N*M)

console.log(answerN, answerM);
```

Comment: @Crash667 glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get `A - B` and `B - A` for your 2 sets `A` and `B`

```js
arr1 = [1,2,3,6]
arr2 = [2,3,4,5,7]

var required1 = arr1.filter((x) => arr2.indexOf(x) < 0)
var required2 = arr2.filter((x) => arr1.indexOf(x) < 0)

console.log(required1, required2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you the array filter method to check for intersection of 2 arrays: Consider the following code which create 2 new arrays that only contain unique values:

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,6];
let arr2 =  [2,3,4,5,7];

let newArr1 = arr1.filter((itm)=>{
    return arr2.indexOf(itm) == -1
});

let newArr2 = arr2.filter((itm)=>{
    return arr1.indexOf(itm) == -1
});
```

Optout of newArr1 and newArr2 are :

```
[1, 6] 
[4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,6],

    arr1Copy = arr1,

    arr2 = [2,3,4,5,7];

arr1 = arr1.filter(function(outerItem){
  return !arr2.some(function(innerItem){
    return outerItem === innerItem;
  })
})

arr2 = arr2.filter(function(outerItem){
  return !arr1Copy.some(function(innerItem){
    return outerItem === innerItem;
  })
})
```